# Learning Python the Hard Way, Exercise 41 headache

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python with the help of Learning Python the Hard Way.
I've reached exercise 41 (Gothons from Planet Percal #25), you can see the full code [>here<](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex41.html)

I understand everything until the last function runner()

```
def runner(map, start)
    next = start

    while True:
        room = map[next]
        print "\n--------"
        next = room()

runner(ROOMS, 'central_corridor')
```

As far as I can understand, **next** is assigned the value of start, being the key of the first function to run. The the while loop is initiated assigning the function at that key to **room**.
Then the function prints out a line of dashes and after that it assigns the returned value of the function call to the variable **next**.

What I don't understand is why the user "sees" the function being called. To me it looks like the function call is just assigned to a variable **next**. I would expect something like **next()** or **room()** being the next line. Secondly I don't understand why the while-loop stops, shouldn't it just continue until false or quit?

These might seem like foolish questions to most of you, but I'm new to the programming game and I don't understand the answers being given to this question elsewhere on this site.

Hope someone can dumb down to my level and explain it to me...

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of some of the questions found using [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+exercise+41). Answers to these questions should help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learn Python the Hard Way, Exercise 41](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909334/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-41)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user sees the function being called, because the function prints things.

The function is actually being called (with "room()") and **the result** of the call is set to *next*.
E.g. If the room is "the_bridge", some stuff is printed and then "death", "escape_pod" or "the_bridge" is returned.

While it's true that "while True:" is an infinite loop, Python has a way to quit the program entirely.

The call **"exit(0)"** quits the whole program right there and then, no questions asked.

Comment: Thanks I think I understand now, just had to wrap my head around the fact that the function call still writes to the screen even though the returned value is being assigned to a variable. That answers both my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how many questions you have, but I'll clarify two things:

(1) `next = room()` works because map is a `dict`, the values of which are functions, so `room = map[next]` retrieves a function from `map`, and stores that function in the variable `room`. The expression `room()` calls that function.

(2) Looking at the code, it does appear that the only exit from the loop will be when the programme exits, or when an exception (if any) is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The Gothon thing is not even Ex 41.
(Maybe it was before, when this post was written? It's Ex 43 now.)
Anyway, it's confusing.
I thought i finally found something relevant to ex 41, then i come here and see this...